How to make Column grids not Resizable?
this problem is in mobile version
i want to cut the gap between "company" and "learn" when i add more informations in the "information" section
I'm searching nonstop for solutions and i cant seem to find one
below is the sample photo SCREENSHOT
and here's my code
<div
          className={tx`grid-cols(2 small-tablet:[1fr_1fr_1fr_80px] small-desktop:[1fr_1fr_1fr] desktop:[1fr_1fr_1fr_80px]) gap-x(3 small-desktop:6) gap-y(4 tablet:[unset]) small-desktop:(justify-items-center w-[480px]) relative grid flex-1 whitespace-nowrap`}
        >
          {footerLinkData?.navChildrenLinks?.map(({ label }) => (
            <div key={`footer-link-${label}`}>
              <h2 className="mb-2.5 uppercase tracking-[0.18em]">{label}</h2>
              <ul className="whitespace-nowrap">
                {label &&
                  findFooterData(label)?.map(({ label, url }) => (
                    <li key={`footer-link-sub-${label}`} className="mb-3 font-serif">
                      <a href={url || "#"} className="mb-3 font-serif hover:underline">
                        {label}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                {label?.toLocaleLowerCase().trim() === "information" && (
                  <button
                    id="ot-sdk-btn"
                    className="ot-sdk-show-settings !hover:bg-transparent !hover:underline !m-0 !border-none !bg-transparent !p-0 !text-left !font-serif !text-[16px] !text-white"
                  >
                    {t("cookies_settings")}
                  </button>
                )}
              </ul>
            </div>

tried this but it seems not showing the results i want
<div className={txgrid-cols(2 small-tablet:[1fr_1fr] small-desktop:[1fr 1fr] desktop:[1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr]) gap-x(3 small-desktop:6) gap-y(3xs tablet:[unset]) small-desktop:(justify-items-center w-[480px]) relative grid flex-1 whitespace-nowrap} style={{ gridTemplateColumns: 'auto auto auto auto' }}> 
